# Chain Command Block not working 1.14.3

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wrote a command: `/clear @p minecraft:book` command set to 'Impulse', 'Unconditional', and 'Need Redstone', then a chain command block : `/tellraw @a "Köszöm"`, set to 'Chain', 'Conditional', and 'Need Redstone'.
The first command block runs:

[image: First command]

But the second chain command block does not run the command:

[image: Second command]

What's the problem here?

Comment: Maybe you didn't actually provide any redstone signal to it? Anyway, your second command isn't using any correct JSON: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands

Comment: @FabianRöling That is actually valid JSON. You can use just a string, which is the [same as only having the `text` tag in the object](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Raw_JSON_text).

Answer (score 1):

For chain command blocks to work that way, the chain command block needs to be set on always active. Otherwise, the chained command would only execute after the command block behind it and facing it has executed *and* if it powered with redstone.

Also, like Fabian Röling said, make sure you provide a redstone signal to the impulse command block.

Comment: @ÁdámKara No problem. Remember, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark if it solved your problem.